# web designer question - How to create a dynamic paragraph or any text in an html file?

Tags: web-development, website-design, tools, software

web designer question - How to create a dynamic paragraph or any text in an html file?

I mean the < p>If I want to change this text portion< /p>

I am a web designer who just know, html, css, adobe dreamweaver, photo shop and corel draw.

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic paragraph?

Comment: If you accept more than 23% of your 48 questions you will get better responses...

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa - I mean if I create a html page, it will be what has been in the paragrah - my question is how does the developer code for it to change.

Comment: I know this is closed, but I think I can answer this, in order for you to dynamically change the content of the said paragraph you would need to use a web programmatic language such as JavaScript.

Comment: this is a "real" question...  @Jeet, you need use jQuery/JavaScript to dynamically change the text contained. <div id="myId">Old text</div> So you want to change the text in this div, using jQuery: $("myId").update("New text");

Comment: @avien - thanks for going ahead for  giving a code line. This SE must have a feature where the first 1 hour to answer my posted question, should be reserved for my favorites, who I think have better explanation methods and who are ready to go ahead just like you did. Thank you one more time.

Comment: you are most welcome!  :)